# Flask-AppBuilder synchronization

Tags: python, flask-appbuilder

I have built an easy template on top of Flask-appBuilder `https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html`. You can see it here: https://flask-appbuilder-skeleton-1.progettazione.repl.co/.
The problem comes when I want to synchronize the code through Github and Visual Studio Code. In fact, if I insert a new user and password from the starting code (in replit), this update is not maintained in github and in Visual Studio Code. What specifically happens is that the app.db file does not appear to update itself.
I hope to find some help from the community

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the error. It was an insidious mistake. The .gitignore file contained the app.db file for that the database was not updated. So I removed this file from .gitgnore and synchronized first Github and then Visual Studio Code. Made the changes in the database from Visual Studio Code and verified the operation through pull on Replit